# R: If TRUE in one vector then use value from second vector, else 1

Tags: r

I have two vectors `h`, the % of bacteria that are removed after washign your hands and `pH`, the probability of washing your hands

```
n=100
probHandHygiene=0.28 # chance of washing hands
pH<-sample(n,x = c("YES","NO"),prob = c(probHandHygiene,1-probHandHygiene),replace = T)

h=1-(1-10.^(-abs(rnorm(n,1.10,0.8129)))) #% reduction of germs IF washed
```

I'd like to multiply the value in h by the equivalent value in pH IF the person washes their hands. If not then leave h value alone. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: "I'd like to multiply the value in h by the equivalent value in pH": pH is a character vector, so how would the multiplication work?

Comment: I guess you want to use `ifelse` function

Comment: Maybe `h[which(pH == "NO")] <- 1` will help, but your question isn't very clear.

Comment: yes, I too would recommend the ifelse function:

`h <- ifelse(pH == "YES", h*probHandHygiene, h)`
which is basically changing h on the condition that if pH is `YES`, then h is `h*probHandHygiene`. if pH is not `YES`, then h remains as h. this should work, if I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: @sweetmusicality yes this what I'm after. Initially I had pH as either 0 or 1... which works if I do h*pH for the cases where pH=1 but not if if pH=0. IF I do if else how can I make sure that it selects the equivalent value in h? I can do it in Matlab but think it should be better in R. Any thought?

Comment: @JohnColeman thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for and works nicely. I'll have to look at "which" more carefully